# What is wrong with typescript deconstructing operator in this snippet?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, react-tsx

My IDE is showing 2 errors in this typescript (tsx) snippet:

```
// @ next line: TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'boolean'.
const SlidesControl = ({ previous: boolean, next: boolean }) => {

  return (
    // @ next line: TS2304: Cannot find names 'previous' and 'next'.
    <nav>TODO {previous} {next}</nav>
  )
}
```

**Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const SlidesControl = ({ previous: boolean, next: boolean })` - rename params (JS feature, ES6), in your case 2 parameters with name boolean

You need type description (TS feature):

```
const SlidesControl = ({ previous, next }: { previous: boolean, next: boolean }) => {
    return (
        <nav>TODO {previous} {next}</nav>
    );
};
```

Another way:

```
type ISlidesControlProps = { previous: boolean; next: boolean };

const SlidesControl = ({ previous, next }: ISlidesControlProps) => {
    return (
        <nav>
            TODO {previous} {next}
        </nav>
    );
};
```

More preferred way in React:

```
type ISlidesControlProps = { previous: boolean; next: boolean };

const SlidesControl: React.FC<ISlidesControlProps> = ({ previous, next }) => {
    return (
        <nav>
            TODO {previous} {next}
        </nav>
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks. isn't there a more compact syntax than rewriting each parameter to specify the type?

Comment: @dragonmnl No, another way create type outside component: `type ISlidesControlProps = { previous: boolean; next: boolean };` and use: `const SlidesControl = ({ previous, next }: ISlidesControlProps) =>`

Comment: Best practice in React: `const SlidesControl: React.FC<ISlidesControlProps> = ({ previous, next })`